# Why is dask read_csv from s3 keeping so much memory?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, amazon-s3, dask

I'm reading in some gzipped data from s3, using dask (a replacement for a SQL query). However, it looks like there is some caching of the data file, or unzipped file somewhere that keeps in system memory. NB this should be runnable, the test data here is used from the pandas test suite in a public s3 bucket.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
import psutil as ps
import os

#for easier vis
mb = 1048576

def mytestfunc(file):
    process = ps.Process(os.getpid())

    print('initial memory: {0}'.format(process.memory_info().rss/mb))
    data = dd.read_csv(file, compression = 'gzip', blocksize = None, storage_options = {'anon':True})

    print('dask plan memory: {0}'.format(process.memory_info().rss/mb))

    data = data.compute()
    print('data in memory: {0}'.format(process.memory_info().rss/mb))
    print('data frame usage: {0}'.format(data.memory_usage(deep=True).sum()/mb))
    return data

process = ps.Process(os.getpid())
print('before function call: {0}'.format(process.memory_info().rss/mb))
out = mytestfunc('s3://pandas-test/large_random.csv.gz')
print('After function call: {0}'.format(process.memory_info().rss/mb))
# out = mytestfunc('s3://pandas-test/tips.csv.gz')
# print('After smaller function call: {0}'.format(process.memory_info().rss/mb))
```

Which gives me:

```
before function call: 76.984375
initial memory: 76.984375
dask plan memory: 92.9921875
data in memory: 224.71484375
data frame usage: 38.14704895019531
After function call: 224.7265625
```

Naively, I would expect the 'after function call' to be the 'before function call' plus the dataframe and a bit of overhead. Here, the gzip is 43mb, and results in an overhead of about 90mb, in my real example, this extra part is about 50gb of extra memory for a 10gb dataframe.

You can see that the memory is freed up if you rerun on another, smaller file - uncomment the rerun on the smaller file to see it. This also shows that the increase is due to the file size - you can switch the order and run 'tips' first and the memory stays at ~90mb.

I am guessing dask, s3fs or pandas is holding the file or the unzipped contents in a buffer somewhere, but I haven't been able to track it down to clear it.

Any ideas on how to reduce this memory use, or free the buffer?

EDIT: An example of the above output for some of my real data - 32 gzipped files:

```
before function call: 70.69921875
initial memory: 70.69921875
dask plan memory: 80.16015625
data in memory: 33991.69921875
data frame usage: 10824.553115844727
After function call: 33991.69921875
```

I understand dask will have a higher peak memory usage than a pandas loop over the same 32 files, but I still don't get why it doesn't get freed up.

Comment: Nice job on making this reproducible - seems to be dask-specific, if I read directly from pandas (which also uses s3fs), the memory pattern does what you'd think

Comment: Good catch - I'm using dask rather than pandas as I have a DB unload with 32 files not just 1. Adding a bounty now!

Comment: You return your `data` from the function and save it into the variable `out` which is still present when you measure "After function call". What is strange here?

Comment: The size of `out` in the example is 38mb, but memory usage after the function call increases by ~130mb, making it seem like there is an uncleared cache or reference somewhere. In my actual data, this is nearly 30gb for a 10gb piece of data. Pandas itself doesnt do the same thing, only increasing memory usage by the data size

Comment: I can confirm that this behaviour is seen with a local .gz file, and also with the same file un-gzipped (although the memory increase in the latter case is smaller).

Comment: If you try with the single-threaded scheduler `dask.set_globals(get=dask.local.get_sync)` then the problem goes away.  I suspect that something is hanging around in the default ThreadPool in `dask.threaded.default_pool`.  One might isolate the problem by using `ThreadPool.get_async` without Dask and seeing if the problem persists

Comment: I've isolated this to Pandas.read_csv + concurrent.futures and raised an issue with Pandas here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/19941

Comment: Thanks a million for tracking this down @MRocklin! I can replicate the github example leak you have, but it looks like it is a little different from mine - the code used there fixes my leak! I guess the best way to proceed will be to make a repro example of my exact issue, and file an issue on the dask github. If you post your example from github, that will be accepted for the answer and bounty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `pandas.read_csv` in threads it appears that the Python process leaks a little memory.  I've reduced it to a problem with `pandas.read_csv` and a `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`.  This is raised on the Pandas issue tracker here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/19941

```
# imports
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import psutil
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

# prep
process = psutil.Process()
e = ThreadPoolExecutor(8)

# prepare csv file, only need to run once
pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((100000, 50))).to_csv('large_random.csv')


# baseline computation making pandas dataframes with threasds.  This works fine

def f(_):
    return pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((1000000, 50)))

print('before:', process.memory_info().rss // 1e6, 'MB')
list(e.map(f, range(8)))
time.sleep(1)  # let things settle
print('after:', process.memory_info().rss // 1e6, 'MB')

# before: 57.0 MB
# after: 56.0 MB

# example with read_csv, this leaks memory
print('before:', process.memory_info().rss // 1e6, 'MB')
list(e.map(pd.read_csv, ['large_random.csv'] * 8))
time.sleep(1)  # let things settle
print('after:', process.memory_info().rss // 1e6, 'MB')

# before: 58.0 MB
# after: 323.0 MB
```